# Max of DateTime (custom) field not recognized in PivotTable

Tags: excel, excel-formula, max, pivot-table, datetime-format

I have some fairly simple raw data where the format of column `LastUsageTime` is custom (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss):

[image: Raw Data]

And a PivotTable:

[image: Pivot Table].

The `LastUsageTime` column is a MAX function (I simply want to display the dates, not count them). The problem is Excel doesn't understand the custom DateTime format of the raw data `LastUsageTime` for some reason. It puts `1900-01-00` everywhere. However, if I copy the text of `LastUsageTime`, paste it to NotePad, then Copy/Paste it back to Excel, it works fine!

However, the raw data is sourced from an external XML file, so when I click refresh, it gets messed up again.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I changed the LastUsageTime format to Date before, and that didn't work either. I can't use a formula for that column because is values are read from an external XML file.

Comment: I added another column to raw data using your formula =DATEVALUE(A2)+TIMEVALUE(A2). Then I did a MAX of this new column in the Pivot Table. That seems to work! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to convert the raw data `LastUsageTime` from string to a date/time value (as Excel does for you by coercion with the copy/paste). Perhaps:

```
 =DATEVALUE(E2)+TIMEVALUE(E2)
```